# Hibernate many-to-many association not updating join table

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many, updates, join

In my app, I have a many-to-many association between the User and Preference entities. Since the join table requires an additional column, I had to break it down into 2 one-to-many associations as such:

User entity :

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, orphanRemoval = true)
public Set<UserPreference> getPreferences() 
{
    return preferences;
}
```

Preference entity :

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "preference", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
public Set<UserPreference> getUserPreferences() 
{
    return userPreferences;
}
```

UserPreference entity :

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
public User getUser() 
{
    return user;
}

public void setUser(User user) 
{
    this.user = user;
}

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "preference_id", nullable = false)
public Preference getPreference() 
{
    return preference;
}

public void setPreference(Preference preference) 
{
    this.preference = preference;
}

@Column(nullable = false, length = 25)
public String getValue() 
{
    return value;
}

public void setValue(String value) 
{
    this.value = value;
}
```

To update one of the preferences, I loop through the user's set of preferences and update the value as such:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/edit-{id}-preference"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String updateUserPreference(@ModelAttribute("userPreference") UserPreference preference, BindingResult result, ModelMap model) 
{
    User loggedInUser = (User)session.getAttribute("loggedInUser");

    for (UserPreference pref : loggedInUser.getPreferences())
    {
        if (Objects.equals(pref.getId(), preference.getId()))
        {
            pref.setValue(preference.getValue());
        }
    }

    userService.update(loggedInUser);

    return "redirect:/users/preferences";
}
```

I have confirmed that the user variable I'm trying to update does indeed contain the new value after this code runs. Even weirder, the value does update on the webpage when the redirect happens but the database does NOT update!  This is the code I'm using to do the update, this class is annotated with @Transactional and every other call to this method (to update the user's role for example) works perfectly:

```
@Override
public void update(User user) 
{
    User entity = dao.findById(user.getId());
    if (entity != null)
    {
        entity.setUserId(user.getUserId());
        entity.setPassword(user.getPassword());
        entity.setFirstName(user.getFirstName());
        entity.setLastName(user.getLastName());
        entity.setRole(user.getRole());
        entity.setPreferences(user.getPreferences());
    }
}
```

This acts like hibernate's session "cache" has the updated value but does not actually persist it. I am using this very same update method style for about 30 other entities and everything works fine. This is my only many-to-many association that I had to break down into 2 one-to-many associations so I have nothing to compare to.

Am I doing something wrong? When I create a user with a new HashSet and persist it, the value is written correctly in the "join table".

*****EDIT*****

For comparison, this is the code I use to create a new user with default preferences. The preferences exist already but the join table is completely empty and this code correctly persists the entities:

```
User user = new User();
        user.setUserId("admin");
        user.setPassword(crypter.encrypt("admin"));
        user.setFirstName("admin");
        user.setLastName("admin");
        user.setRole(roleService.findByName("Admin"));

        Set<UserPreference> userPreferences = new HashSet<>();

        Preference preference = preferenceService.findByName("anchorPage");
        UserPreference userPreference = new UserPreference();
        userPreference.setUser(user);
        userPreference.setPreference(preference);
        userPreference.setValue("System Statistics");
        userPreferences.add(userPreference);

        preference = preferenceService.findByName("showOnlyActivePatients");
        userPreference = new UserPreference();
        userPreference.setUser(user);
        userPreference.setPreference(preference);
        userPreference.setValue("true");
        userPreferences.add(userPreference);

        user.setPreferences(userPreferences);

        userService.save(user);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using merge? That is what you are cascading after all and you have modified a detached object and need to merge back the changes:

```
public void update(User user)  {
  dao.merge(user);
}
```

EDIT: for clarity this replaces the old update method, so it should be called from the client side with loggedInUser, just like before.

EDIT 2: as noted in the comments merge will update all fields. The old update method also seems to do that? Optimistic locks (version numbers) can be used to guard against overwriting other changes by mistake.

Comment: It's not a detached entity because he is fetching it from the database before setting the attributes. And as he said, it's working for others attributes and others entities. He also explicitly tells that the update works for the role, for example. I believe that explicitly calling `merge()` could help the author to solve his problem, but I also believe this is not what the author wants.

Comment: "It" (loggedInUser which is obtained from the session) is almost certainly a detached entity. The code modifies loggedInUser, which was presumably read in a previous session and detached, and then invokes update. Calling merge will attach it to the new session and merge in the changes, saving them. As far as I can see that is exactly what the author wants? If not I'm sure he will say so.

Comment: I agree with you that `loggedInUser` is a detached entity. But please take a look on the first line of the `update` method: `User entity = dao.findById(user.getId());`. If I am not wrong, from this point onwards, he is updating an attached entity. Could you please clarify this for me? Maybe I misread something. Sorry for the comments, but I don't want to start a war here, just a better understanding of the problem and solution.

Comment: Sure, but the first line of my update method is dao.merge(user). I'm replacing his update method entirely. In both cases the user that is passed to the update method is loggedInUser. He reads the user and assigns it to entity and copies the values from loggedInUser to entity. I'm leaving that to Hibernate. The merge method will read the user from the database and sort things out. Hope that made it clear? If not I don't mind further comments, perhaps I need to clarify the answer in some way.

Comment: Now I saw your edit "replace the update method". Sure, I agree 100% with you that this solves the problem of not updating that list. But I can see a new "probable" problem with your answer: your call to merge will always update every attribute of the user class, which may not be what the author wants. If you do happen to know a way to solve this, please add it to your answer because this would help me a lot. I also always use `merge` calls and don't know how to solve this.

Comment: Looking at his update method he already seems top update every field (even the password which certainly hasn't changed), but I agree that this may cause problems. My answer is to use optimistic locks (version numbers) to avoid overwriting fields by mistake and to optionally handle the conflict on the client side, but if the current code base doesn't use versions it may be a lot of work to add it everywhere.

Comment: Merge indeed works!  I got this style of update method from way back when i learned Spring MVC / Hibernate integration over a year ago.  Care to elaborate why i'm getting this behavior in this scenario and why merge works?

Comment: It is explained in detail in https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/persist-save-merge-saveorupdate-whats-difference-one-use. When you call the update method, Hibernate will only select the entity which you provided as a method parameter. But when you call JPA’s merge method, Hibernate will also select all associations with CascadeType.MERGE. (Direct quote from article). Great that it worked!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
entity.setPreferences(user.getPreferences());
```

Do something like:

```
for( UserPreference uf : user.getPreferences() ) {
    entity.getPreferences().add( uf );
}
```

The main difference here is that you aren't changing the list reference, which is managed by Hibernate, and is only adding elements to it.

Comment: setPreferences() requires a Set of UserPreference objects.  This would be passing a UserPreference object to that method and would not compile.

Comment: Sorry @Martin, my mistake. You are correct! I updated my answer. Please take a look.

Comment: @Martin, have you checked my updated answer? Could you please tell me if it solved your problem?